# Parsing custom parameters from an Axis2 exposed POJO

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have a web service operation that I am exposing with Axis2.

Let's say it's like this:

```
public class MyService{

  public String helloworld(String yourName){
    return "Hello " + yourName;
  }
}
```

This is a pretty simple web service. My question is how do I parse more complex parameters?
For example, I want to pass more than just strings, and I also want some parameters to be optional and some parameters to may also be nested.

Answer (score 0):

Use [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) and method overloading.