# Variable number of arguments in an Axis2 POJO

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, pojo

I have a web service that I built with Axis2/Java.  The web service will take in a list of objects and will process them. I'll use the following operation as an example.

```
public class AddToDatabaseService{

  public void addToDatabase(String name1, String name2, String name3, ....)
  {
    //add names to database
  }
}
```

I want the caller of my web service to use a URI like:
http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/addToDatabase?name1=Joe&name2=Bob&name3=Kelly&name4=...

I'm aware this is not compilable code and the idea is still there. Is this even possible with SOAP-based web services? I know this is possible to do with RESTful services because you can just take the HttpServletRequest request object and do Enumeration enumeration = request.getParameterNames() and iterate through them.

I'm looking for the equivalent of that in web services POJO's with Axis2.
A link or an sample program would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing custom parameters from an Axis2 exposed POJO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390249/parsing-custom-parameters-from-an-axis2-exposed-pojo)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390249/parsing-custom-parameters-from-an-axis2-exposed-pojo)

Solution was to use a [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) parameter